# Values of $a$ such that exactly $6$ integers in the interval $(-5,15)$ solve the inequation:

Tags: inequality

$$8x+\sqrt {8x} \ge 5+7x-a+\sqrt {5+7x-a}$$

I dont know how to solve this. squaring to get rid of all the roots is filthy, and I dont know how to limit a so that exactly six values are the solution. Any help is a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=8x,g(x)=5+7x-a$. Note that we have $f(x)\ge 0,g(x)\ge 0$, i.e.
$$x\ge 0\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ x\ge\frac{a-5}{7}\tag1$$

Then,
$$\begin{align}f(x)+\sqrt{f(x)}\ge g(x)+\sqrt{g(x)}&\iff f(x)-g(x)+\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{g(x)}\ge 0\\&\iff \left(\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{g(x)}\right)\left(\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{g(x)}+1\right)\ge 0\\&\iff \sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{g(x)}\ge 0\\& \iff f(x)\ge g(x) \\&\iff 8x\ge 5+7x-a\\&\iff x\ge 5-a\tag2\end{align}$$

Now, note that we need to have $8\lt \frac{a-5}{7}\le 9$ or $8\lt 5-a\le 9$.

Comment: I still dont know how to define a so that exactly six integer solutions exist..

Comment: @JohnDoe: I added a bit. Take a look.

Comment: The answer is supposed to be $[-4,-3)\cup (61,68]$. Why do they have to equal nine?

Comment: @JohnDoe: Sorry, I was wrong. I edited my answer. Note that the $6$ integers have to be $9,10,11,12,13,14$.

Comment: Why not any other group of three?

Comment: @JohnDoe: Since we have $x\color{red}{\ge} 0, x\color{red}{\ge}\frac{a-5}{7}$ and $x\color{red}{\ge} 5-a$, the $6$ integers have to be them. (I'm not sure if I answered your question...)

Comment: Im sure you answered it, I just probably dont follow what youve said because I am dumb and sleepy

Comment: Okay, this really isn't entering my head. Can you spell it out for me? I'm sorry fir bothering you this much

Comment: @JohnDoe: Maybe drawing a number line helps. Every inequality has $x\ge$ form, so the $6$ integers are what I wrote. I hope this helps:)